# JavaScript localStorage returning 1?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to do this simple code, although when I read the documentation for the localStorage. Im not quite understanding why it is returning 1. The below code is just a part of the HTML file. So if we for example select the id of maxAdult value 6. It will return 1. Is there a problem with my original HTML and this should be working fine or am I missing something?

**First HTML**

```
<select id="maxAdult">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select id="maxChild">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<script>
  var store = document.getElementById("maxAdult");
  var value = store.value;
  localStorage.setItem("max", value);
</script>
```

**Second HTML**

```
<script>
  var passen = localStorage.max;
  document.write("<br><strong style='font-size: 16px'>Number of Passengers: 
  </strong><br>");
  document.write(passen);
</script>
```

**Output**

```
Number of Passengers:
1
```

Comment: Because you only set it on page load, not when select is changed

Comment: You're storing the value at page load, you should store the value after they make a selection.  And I think you need to wait for localStorage to be ready.

Comment: You need to use the `onchange` event and set the value of the localstorage everytime

Comment: @MichaelFuller `localStorage` is not asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @charlietfl has said in the comments, you have to actually have to listen to the `change` event in order to update the localStorage when the `<select>` element value is updated, i.e.:

```
var store = document.getElementById("maxAdult");

// Listen to onchange
store.addEventListener('change', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("max", this.value);
});
```

This is because JS is not reactive in nature and the value of `store` does not automagically update its counterpart in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your localStorage, but you need to write an event handler for when the value changes. As it stands, your code is only run once when the page loads. Here's a simple example using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```html
<select id="maxAdult">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select id="maxChild">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<script>
  var store = document.getElementById("maxAdult");
  store.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
</script>
```